# Java Date oddity

Tags: java, datetime

Out of curiosity, why do I receive an `IllegalArgumentException` for the `MONTH` in the below test case?

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
      c.setLenient(false);
      Date d = new Date();

      c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
      c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
      c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);

      d = c.getTime();  //Exception is not thrown until this line

      System.out.println(d.toString());
    }
}
```

I looked at the GregorianCalendar which is the default on my system, and realize that the `MONTH` field would in fact be the first one to differ in the two Feb 30, vs March 2 in this case, but shouldn't this `IllegalArgumentException` be what causes the overflow, or was it just deemed to difficult to "discover"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because February always has less than 30 days.  And you are setting the day on the  `Calendar` instance to 30.  So, when you try to create an invalid `Date`, Java will not let you because that would be an invalid date and you have chosen `setLienient(false)`.

Try the following:

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);
```

That should work.

This is ultimately caused because you are calling `c.setLenient(false);`.  This causes Java to be strict about the dates it allows.

See the Javadoc for the method:

[`public void setLenient(boolean lenient)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

Comment: ...or 29 days - but you don't know which until after you've set the year.

Comment: I modified the question to show where the exception is thrown.  You are actually allowed to set an invalid date.  If you take out the call to c.setLenient(false), the program compiles and runs just fine.  You just receive a date of March 2, 2010.

Comment: @Scott, I made some edits.  The problem still stems from the fact that feb 30 is not a valid date.  The validity of the date is not checked until the call to `getTime()`.

Comment: I understand why I am receiving the exception, I am just disagreeing with the cause of the exception.  In this case at least it seems that the DAY_OF_MONTH is what is really the invalid field.  This is the strack trace I receive: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2481) I expected: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DAY_OF_MONTH at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2481)

Comment: @Scott, you can really look at it either way.  Java is thinking about it like so - "If the day is 30, then February an invalid month."  And you are looking at it like - "If the month is February, then 30 is an invalid day."  Either way makes sense.